# Original C hello, world program from Kernighan and Ritchie not compiling

Tags: c, printf, token

I'm trying to learn C using the Kernighan and Ritchie book (The C Bible).  Upon trying to compile the first problem using tcc and MinGW (using Windows).  It gave me an error message.  The most detailed one came from Min GW:
helloworld.c:3:8: error: expected ')' before '(' token

Here is my program:

```
main()

(

    printf("hello, world\n");

)
```

As far as I can tell it follows the book to the dot.  Is this now out of date?  I've looked for this and still can't find what I've done wrong.  Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: main()

{

printf("hello, world\n");

}

Comment: how dare you say K&R wrote uncompilable code!!

Comment: What edition are you using? I don't believe any edition would miss the **required** `#include <stdio.h>`: mine (the 2nd, page 6) doesn't :)

Comment: It says copyright 1978, it must be the 1st.  The program is on page 6.

Comment: @user1031369: must the be the first, yes. I wasn't aware of that particular difference between the 1st and 2nd version :(

Answer (score 5):

`( blahblah; )` is not the same as `{ blahblah; }`, and your book might be a bit outdated (though the code should be fine to learn from, even if some requires changes). Current standard C would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`main(void)` could also be `main(int argc, char *argv[])` if you want to read command line arguments.

Comment: I would not bet that the example in K&R includes `stdio.h`. K&R C had implicit prototypes, and it just happens that this use of `printf()` works with the implicit prototype.

Comment: Ok, in the book they looked so similar, but now I can see.  Gosh I feel so stupid.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pascal: Even with implicit prototypes, the `printf` must have a definite prototype in scope because it is a function taking a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @pmg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#.22Hello.2C_world.22_example Note that I said "this use of `printf()`".

Comment: @Pascal: I stand corrected ... I thought pre-ANSI C also required prototypes for functions taking a variable number of arguments (even when the aguments relative to the `...` weren't used).

Comment: `return 0` may be omitted, but that's a special case for `main` only (C99).

Comment: Omitting the return statement is also valid in any function, even if it's expected to return a value, as long as the return value never gets used. (Of course it's still very bad style.) The only thing that's a special case about `main` is that the exit status is automatically 0 if it's omitted.

Answer (score 5):

You are mistakenly using `(` and `)` instead of `{` and `}`. And presumably the code in the book has a `#include` statement in order to declare `printf`.

Comment: no #include statement was mentioned, but upon making these changes the program now compiles.

Comment: I think there is a modern version of the K&R book.

Answer (score 2):

You used parentheses instead of brackets. It should be

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The symbols that begin and end a function's body are curly braces, not parentheses. It should look like:

```
main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

That said, this is indeed *woefully* out of date.

Comment: Is that to say that it isn't even worth using this book?

Comment: K&R has historical significance and is an interesting read if you want to learn about the history of C, but it doesn't reflect modern coding practice or even the current syntax of the language.

Comment: Use the book. It is worth it. Get your compiler to warn about as much as it can, try to figure out if the warning is due to changes in the language and ask here if you're stuck.

Comment: Okay, to be honest I really was reading it for the purpose of getting some background for c++.  I really appreciate the quick responses.  This is a great community.

Comment: C isn't C++. ;) They're cousins, not twins.

Comment: It was my understanding that C++ was more the daughter of C.  Is this inaccurate?  I want to understand and know both.

Comment: When C++ "was born" maybe it was a strict superset of C. But since then both languages evolved, sometimes differently. Nowadays, there are things in C that C++ doesn't have; there are valid similar constructs for both languages whose behaviours are different in C and C++. And, most importantly, the idiomatic ways to do stuff are different in the 2 languages. If you learn both languages at the same time you will mess things up; if you learn first one the other you will mess things up.